# Expand Root Volume when Creating Ec2 from API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

if you are creating an EC2 from Nodejs api call [Runinstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#runInstances-property)

I found it tricky to expand the root volume if you are creating an EC2 from AMI comes with low disk Space 8GB usually 
I you use

using this block will add another EBS Volume to the EC2 without expanding the root volume

```
 BlockDeviceMappings: [
 {
   DeviceName: "/dev/sdh", 
   Ebs: {
   VolumeSize: 100
}
```

}
  ],

what can we do to Expand the root volume ?

Comment: yes the block device mapping allows you add extra disk to the instance

Comment: what's tricky about it? I usually look up the block device mapping of the image, and then simply use that but change the VolumeSize to the size I want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `modifyVolume(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request`and you can also modify volume attribute by `modifyVolumeAttribute(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request.`

It is mentioned in same documentation link you have shared.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even I have some issue while calling run-instances, I wanted to exclude some volume but it's not possible in the run-instance
but if you do the operation through AWS Console, AWS UI allows doing the same like expand the volume and exclude volume

You can launch the instance using the run-instance and do the volume modify and increase the size of the volume in another command.

if you find any other solution, please let me also know by answering the below question
[Exclude EBS volume while create instance from the AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320020/exclude-ebs-volume-while-create-instance-from-the-ami)